# How to configure my gmail account so that mail send by an app do not save the mail in the sent folder

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I have an app that sends mails using a gmail account (gsuite) with app-passwords. Can I prevent the email to be saved in the *sent* folder?

So basically *fire and forget*.

Is it possible?

Comment: *So basically fire and forget.* Fire, wait until sent, delete, then forget.

Comment: So it's not possible and I have to "cleanup" myself?

Comment: Your particular task seems to be very rare. Whereas the mailserver realises the most common algorythm. If you need some modifying you must perform it "by hands". I think so...

Comment: If rules can be setup on whichever platform you're using, try If the mail has "some specific content", delete it. you might even mark it junk and set clear junk automatically.